# use asp.net to re-order images in server

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net website where people can upload their image files.
I have code to upload multiple files at once.

I also have a requirement where I need to populate a List
that lists image file names in order.

So after a user uploaded 10 image files, he should be able to arrange pictures in any order he likes.

I was thinking of using ListBox showing file names, but when there are many files, it is difficult to remember which file shows what image.
I was also reading about drag-drop using jQuery but have no experience in jQuery. AJAX and couldn't find an example that show images on screen and drag and drop them into box1, box2, box3....

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable would serve you nicely I think.

Comment: I didn't have any experience in jQuery and jQuery UI until I learned it, on my own.

Comment: thank you guys. i will check out the sortable page.

Comment: ok so I tried jquery sortable and while it does sort things on screen, i don't know how I can get the sorted list in asp.net.

Comment: Ok. Presumably you have a database behind this? And your table contains a sort-order column of some kind?